# I want to know why the results are repeated in the table view

Tags: ios, swift

I get the value through the php file of the web server.

I hope to bring the results from DB when I search.

There are two problems with my code now.

1. Spelling that is not included in the values contained in the DB also produces results.
2. The results come out repeatedly.

First of all, this is the json result I'm getting.

```
[
  {
    "name" : "name1",
    "id" : "1"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name2",
    "id" : "2"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name3",
    "id" : "3"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name4",
    "id" : "4"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name5",
    "id" : "5"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name6",
    "id" : "6"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name7",
    "id" : "7"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name8",
    "id" : "8"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name9",
    "id" : "9"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name10",
    "id" : "10"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name11",
    "id" : "11"
  },
  {
    "name" : "name12",
    "id" : "12"
  }
]
```

But in emulators, the results come out this way.

```
name1
name1
name2
name1
name2
name3
.
.
.
```

I wonder why the results come out like this.

This is my code.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    var arrID = [String]()
    var arrName = [String]()
    
    var filteredData = [String]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    
    @IBOutlet var mytableview: UITableView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        searchBar.delegate = self
        self.mytableview.delegate = self
        self.mytableview.dataSource = self
        
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return filteredData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        let url = "http://url/name.php?name=" + searchText
        print(url)
        
        AF.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { (myresponse) in
            switch myresponse.result {
            case .success:
                let myresult = try? JSON(data: myresponse.data!)
                print(myresult!)
                
                let resultArray = myresult!
                
                self.arrID.removeAll()
                self.arrName.removeAll()
                
                for i in resultArray.arrayValue {
                    let id = i["id"].stringValue
                    self.arrID.append(id)
                    let name = i["name"].stringValue
                    self.arrName.append(name)
                    self.filteredData.append(contentsOf: self.arrName)
                }
                
                if searchText == "" {
                    self.filteredData = []
                } else {
                    for data in self.filteredData {
                        if data.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                            self.filteredData.append(data)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                self.mytableview.reloadData()
                
            case .failure:
                print(myresponse.error!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.filteredData.append(contentsOf: self.arrName)`, you can't do this inside the loop. And you should work with a struct instead of separate arrays for id and name. And do you really need to download the data _every time_ the search bar content is changed?

Comment: I did that because I wanted to bring the result every time the search term changed.
But from what you say, I guess that's not how it should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to change this:

```
for i in resultArray.arrayValue {
    let id = i["id"].stringValue
    self.arrID.append(id)
    let name = i["name"].stringValue
    self.arrName.append(name)
    self.filteredData.append(contentsOf: self.arrName)
}
```

To this:

```
for i in resultArray.arrayValue {
    let id = i["id"].stringValue
    self.arrID.append(id)
    let name = i["name"].stringValue
    self.arrName.append(name)
}
self.filteredData.append(contentsOf: self.arrName)
```

I'm confused why you are doing this, though:

```
for data in self.filteredData {
    if data.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
        self.filteredData.append(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
No wonder the result came out twice below.

Comment: Two things about this answer, OP should make note of the logical contradiction that is pointed out in that data is added to `filteredData` both when loading data and then also when filtering and secondly since `filteredData` might not be empty I think it would be better to do `self.filteredData = self.arrName` rather than appending the array during loading

Answer (score 0):

Because for each entry in your JSON you add all the data you read so far to your filtered array again. And then you finally add all the entries that contain your search text to filteredArray again.

The first issue will be fixed by removing the line

```
self.filteredData.append(contentsOf: self.arrName)
```

from the first loop.

The second loop that does the filtering then needs to be changed to iterate over ˋarrNameˋ instead and you need to clear ˋfilteredDataˋ before.

An even better option would be to use the filter method:

```
filteredData = arrName.filter { data in
    data.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
}
```